# R: Removing a slash and one followed character from strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have some race data where the values contain '\n', such as in 'Biracial or Multiracial\nBlack or African American\nWhite or Caucasian' or 'White or Caucasian\nBlack or African American'. Is there a way to remove the slash and the followed letter n? (preferably using `str_remove` or `gsub`)

Comment: @AndreWildberg Thank you very much! I used the `str_remove_all` when there are multiple line breaks in one entry.

Comment: @AndreWildberg why not just `gsub('\n', ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double \ for escaping.

For instance:

```
library(stringr)

str_remove("Multiracial\nBlack" , "\\n")
```

And the same for `gsub()`:

```
gsub("\\n", "", "Multiracial\nBlack")
```

Output:

```
[1] "MultiracialBlack"
```

I hope you consider \n to be line brake, not two symbols.

Comment: Hi @asd-tm, you are correct. That was a line break in the Excel file. Thank you very much! It works perfectly, with `str_remove_all` when there are multiple line breaks in one entry.

Comment: why not just `gsub('\n', ...)`?

Comment: @Onyambu I forget to escape things from time to time so I prefer using escaping even when it does not change anything. And I met expressions successfully detecting strings by base R and not by `stringr::` because of escaping absence.